# the meaning of $f_+’(t) = \int_{(t,1]} {{s^{ - 1}}\mu (ds)}$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

If $\mu$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$,
$$f_+’(t) = \int_{(t,1]} {{s^{ - 1}}\mu (ds)}\quad \mbox{for } 0<t<1.$$
Given $\mu(\{0\})=f(0+)$, how can we calculate $$\int_{(0,1]} {{s^{ - 1}}\mu (ds)}.$$

Is it $f_+’(0)$?  Here, $f_+’(0)$ can be $+\infty$.

Thanks for any suggestions;)